# idiomatic way to combine levels of a categorical factor

Tags: r, dplyr

Here's a trivial example of what I'm trying to do:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(Species2 = ifelse(Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica"), "other", as.character(Species)) %>% as.factor) %>%
  str
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  6 variables:
#   $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
# $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
# $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
# $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
# $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
# $ Species2    : Factor w/ 2 levels "Other","versicolor": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

However, if I want to do multiple merges, I'd end up with deeply nested `ifelse` statements, which I'm trying to avoid. What's the most elegant way to do this? Preferably I can incorporate the solution into a dplyr pipeline.

Comment: The base R method would be to change the levels after checking the `levels(iris$Species)`, i.e.   `levels(iris$Species) <- c('other', 'versicolor', 'other')`

Comment: so after some more research `plyr::revalue` seems to fit the bill, but if I'm combining many levels into one there's a bit of redundant typing, so i'm going to investigate coming up with a wrapper that takes a named list...

Comment: I think you should put your classification rules into a data.frame, `data.frame(Species=c("setosa", "virginica"),Species2="other")` and merge it in. You mention "multiple merges", so maybe that is already what you meant...

Comment: Expanding on akrun's comment, you could use a "list" in `"levels<-"`: `xx = factor(sample(letters[1:5], 15, TRUE), letters[1:5]); xx; levels(xx) = list(ab = c("a", "b"), c = "c", de = c("d", "e")); xx`

Comment: also see `car::recode()`, although its interface is a little clunky

Answer (score 1):

You can use `match`:

```
species.keep <- c("setosa", "virginica", "other")
iris %>% mutate(Species2 = species.keep[match(Species, species.keep, nomatch=3)])
```

We use the `nomatch` argument to `match` to map to `"other"` at the last position of our `species.keep` vector for any species that are not in previous positions.  Note this assumes `"other"` is not a valid species.  You'll have to add the `as.factor` etc., but this should get to what you want.  `match` is the baseline mapping function in R.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to populate the initial array with the possible matches, probably you will need to use something like `sapply`. Then you can use that array to populate Species2:

```
s <- sapply(levels(iris$Species), 
            function(x) {
                         if (x %in% c("setosa", "virginica")) 
                           x = "Other" 
                         else 
                           x = x
                        }, 
            simplify = F) 

iris %>% 
  mutate(Species2 = (as.character(s[Species])) %>% as.factor) %>%
  str
```